# d3.js drag Point on more than 1 Graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have 4 Graphs that Display some Data. Now I want to drag Points on all 4 Graphs.

What I already have is.

```
var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
    .on("drag", dragmove);

function dragmove(d) {
    var x = d3.event.x;
    var y = d3.event.y;
    console.log("["+x+";"+y+"]");
    d3.select(this).attr("transform", "translate(" + x + "," + y + ")");
    refresh();
}
```

How can I Achieve the drag is made in chart1 ... chart4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call the drag behavior function on all elements that you want to apply drag behavior to, in all 4 charts.

```
chart1.selectAll("circle").call(drag);
...
chart4.selectAll("circle").call(drag);
```

Here's an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/paulitto/1njh8uLu/3/) how it works with multiple charts

Comment: Goes into the Right direction, but what I want is that the dot is moved in all Charts. I have 4 Charts with different Scalings and need that behavior.

Comment: In the example I showed dots can be moved in all charts. Or you mean, you want to allow moving dots from one chart to another?

Comment: When moving an dot in the one Chart that exact Dot shall be moved in the other Chart Aswell. The Charts are identical and all show the same Informations but in other scalings of x and y axis.

Comment: then, I suppose, in your dragmove function you need to move not only d3.select(this) but also selectt corresponding points on other graphs and move them as well according to their scales.